# Django ORM for counting reference from ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-orm

I have two models: `Industry` and `Employer`, as per below:

```
class Industry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)


class Employer(models.Model):
    industry = models.ForeignKey(Industry)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

The problem is that not all of the industries have employers yet... I want to get a list of all industries that have atleast one employer mapped to them, rather than getting them all. Is this possible with the ORM not with just regular SQL? I tried to find this in the django docs and coudlnt..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic problem for [Django Annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/)

Try:

```
from django.db.models import Count
Industry.objects.annotate(num_employers=Count('employer').filter(num_employers__gt=0)
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not entirely sure if you want to use 'employer_set' or just 'employer'. I'm pretty sure in this case, it's just 'employer', but correct me if I'm wrong, and I'll edit.